# How can I make a checkbox be always checked by getting its value?

Tags: jquery, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

For this task I'm working with laravel-livewire, alpine.js and bootstrap.

I have a modal in my screen which contains a table where the user can select up to 9 columns to show. There is one column that needs to appear by default in all cases (so it needs to be checked by default) and as I said, the user will select another 9.

Here is the construction of the table:

```
<tbody>
   <template x-for="column in data" >
      <tr x-show="column.title != ''">
         <td class="text-left ml-4"> 
            <span x-html="column.title"></span> 
         </td>
         <td class="text-left">
            <input 
               x-model="selectedColumns" 
               id="selectColumns" 
               class="selectColumns" 
               type="checkbox" 
               :value=column.field
               >
         </td>
      </tr>
   </template>
</tbody>
```

In the `:value` attribute, I'm receiving names of my database fields. The one that I need to appear by default for example is  named `sap_id`

The code I'm using to limit columns selection:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[id='selectColumns']").change(function () {
        var maxAllowed = 8;
        var selected = $("input[id='selectColumns']:checked").length;
        
        if (selected > maxAllowed) {
            $("input[id='selectColumns']").not(":checked").attr("disabled",true);
        } else {
            $("input[id='selectColumns']").not(":checked").removeAttr('disabled');
        }       
    });
});
```

And finally, the function that displays the selected columns in the screen:

```
function displaySelected(selectedColumns) {
    let newColumns = columns.filter((column) => {
       return selectedColumns.includes(column.field);
    });

    datatable.destroy();
    $('#selectColumnsModal').modal('hide');
    Clients.init(newColumns);
}
```

So, summing up: If the `:value` attribute equals to `sap_id` the checkbox needs to be checked by default and may not be unchecked. I'm having trouble on making this work. Actually I don't even know if this is the best way for doing this task... So if you guys could help me with that I would be very pleased. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Slightly off topic:  `$("input[id='selectColumns']:checked").length` indicates that you have multiple checkboxes with the id=selectColumns.  IDs must be unique within a page.   You can probablt just remove the id= from the html and use `$("input.selectColumns:checked")`

Comment: You probably want a server-side solution rather than js.   When building the HTML if the ID=sap_id then make it checked and readonly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I created a list for default columns: `defaultSelected`, that we can add to the selected list in the `init()` function of our `columnSelector` [component](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data). Furthermore in the `isDisabled(field)` function we also check whether the respective column is present in `defaultSelected` or not.

Note: uncomment the `document.addEventListener` line, it's disabled because of SO code snippet window only.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
<script>
//document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('columnSelector', () => ({
    defaultSelected: ['sap_id'],
    maxSelected: 3,
    data: [
      {title: 'SAP ID', field: 'sap_id'},
      {title: 'Col #1', field: 'field1'},
      {title: 'Col #2', field: 'field2'},
      {title: 'Col #3', field: 'field3'},
      {title: 'Col #4', field: 'field4'},
      {title: 'Col #5', field: 'field5'},
    ],
    selectedColumns: [],

    init() {
      this.selectedColumns.push(...this.defaultSelected)
    },

    isDisabled(field) {
      return this.defaultSelected.includes(field) ||
             (this.selectedColumns.length === this.maxSelected &&
              !this.selectedColumns.includes(field))
    },
  }))
//})
</script>

<div x-data="columnSelector">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <template x-for="column in data" >
          <tr x-show="column.title != ''">
            <td class="text-left ml-4">
                <span x-html="column.title"></span>
            </td>
            <td class="text-left">
                <input
                  x-model="selectedColumns"
                  class="selectColumns"
                  type="checkbox"
                  :value=column.field
                  :disabled="isDisabled(column.field)"
                  >
            </td>
          </tr>
      </template>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  Selected columns: <span x-text="`${selectedColumns.length}/${maxSelected}`"></span>
</div>
```